# How to switch on Samsung Galaxy when Power Button jams?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot, power-on

Since my smartphone's casing is so tight, I had to press the buttons harder, until the power button got permanently stuck. Now I dont't know how to switch on my Samsung Galaxy without using its power button.

I already tried booting into the "[download mode](https://visihow.com/Can%27t_turn_on_Samsung_S5_power_button_not_responding)" but it does not work.

Comment: Even if you would manage to power up your device you won't get far because long pressing the power button for ~10 seconds usually initiates a hard reboot. Remove the casing and get your device to a repair shop that is IMHO the only thing you can do.

Comment: that's sad to hear. but, thank you.